# Conventional default route in asp.net core not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I can't seem to get my default route working in ASP.NET Core 2.0, am I overlooking something ?

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMvc(routes => 
        {
            routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}/{id?}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

when I browse to the URL, nothing happens, and it does not redirect to Home ?

Comment: what url are you trying ?

Comment: http://localhost:5000

Comment: when I go to localhost:5000/Home, it shows the page. It just doesn't take it as default ...

Comment: Don't you need to define "template"? Just asking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just remove the `[Route("[controller]")]` decoration on the controller.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

With the default routing you registered in the `UseMvc` method with the conventional route patterns, now it should work for `yourBaseUrl` and `yourBaseUrl\Home` and `yourBaseUrl\Home\Index`

Typically you use the `[Route("[controller]")]` attribute on a controller level as a route prefix for all the routes on that controller to create custom attribute route definitions for your action methods.

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("myseofriendlyurlslug")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now your action method will be accessible via `yourBaseUrl/Home/myseofriendlyurlslug`

Keep in mind that, when using attribute routing like above, the conventional routing pattern won't work.

Comment: I ran into this too, makes sense now that I think about it. Attributes should prioritize over default routing templates.

Answer (score 2):

this work fine

//Startup.cs

```
...

app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

...
```

//HomeController.cs

```
...

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

....
```